# Apache HTTP Server Docker Image - Cleaner configuration in Dockerfile wanted

Tags: apache, docker, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile that does extra configuration of the official Apache HTTP Server Docker image. Is there a cleaner way to do this inside a Dockerfile? I'm very unfamiliar with Apache HTTP Server configuration and was just about able to cobble this together. (The reason for enabling mod_rewrite is because I use it in a .htaccess file in the htdocs folder)

```
ARG BUILD_DIR=/usr/src/app

FROM node:10.13.0-alpine as build
ARG BUILD_DIR
WORKDIR $BUILD_DIR
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY src src
COPY public public
RUN npm run build

FROM httpd:2.4.37-alpine
ARG BUILD_DIR
ENV SERVER_CONTAINER_NAME=server
COPY --from=build $BUILD_DIR/build htdocs
RUN sed -i 's,#\(LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so\),\1,g' conf/httpd.conf \
  && sed -i -e '/<Directory "\/usr\/local\/apache2\/htdocs">/,/<\/Directory>/{s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/}' conf/httpd.conf \
  && sed -i 's,#\(LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so\),\1,g' conf/httpd.conf \
  && sed -i 's,#\(LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so\),\1,g' conf/httpd.conf \
  && echo 'ProxyRequests off' >> conf/httpd.conf \
  && echo 'ProxyPass /ws ws://${SERVER_CONTAINER_NAME}:8080/ws interpolate' >> conf/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be cleaner to keep the modified versions of those config files outside of the image, and then copy them into the container during the build.

Alternatively, you could put all the shell commands in a script. During the build, COPY the script into the container. At the end of the script add something like this:

```
  exec /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -f /etc/apache2/apache2.conf -DFOREGROUND
```

to start your server. Then have docker invoke the script as

```
CMD [ "/MyScript.sh" ]
```